# RHEL package for libmono-winforms package

Tags: linux, mono

We want to run UI based .net application on RHEL through mono. But we are not able to run UI based application. So some places I have that libmono-winforms package required. So please let me know the package location. Immediate help is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Ashutosh

Answer (score 0):

The mono-winforms package exists in the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). Once you add that repository you can run as root: yum install mono-winforms.